# Prevent card from expanding in a card-deck

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a card-deck where I would like to keep the same adaptive width. The issue is that when "rows of cards" that can handle 3 cards, using 5 cards will left the two remaining cards taking the whole width of the container.

## What it should look like (iPad example)

[image: iPad Fixed]

## What it look like (iPad example)

[image: iPad]

Here is the same issue on a widescreen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOEF6.png

## The code (5 cards example)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">

        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>

        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
        <div class="w-100 d-none d-xl-block"><!-- wrap every 4 on xl--></div>


        <div class="card mb-4">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="//placehold.it/500x280" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
   
    </div>
</div>
```

I saw this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19650 and tried using

```
.card {
    width: initial;
}
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the docs, [card-deck's aren't yet responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#card-layout) so it's going to be hard to get the desired layout without a lot of extra CSS. This is because of the way the flexbox children (cards) grow in width.

Use full height cards in the grid instead...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
                ....
            </div>
        </div>
          .... (more columns with cards)
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/hs12dUxHnQ